# o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Bootstrap broker <hostname>:9092 disconnected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume messages from Kafka topic using Spring Kafka consumer.However I seeing the below error. This works fine when I consume messages from a kafka topic set up in my local machine -

[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Bootstrap broker `<hostname>:9092`disconnected

I am able to read the messages using command line

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic ctp_verbose_amcs --from-beginning --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

**Code**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerConfig.class);

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress:localhost:9092}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${groupId:amcs-tas}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new ConciseMessageDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Error Message in Server Log**

```
[2017-09-20 14:33:44,448] ERROR Closing socket for <hostname>:9092-10.251.127.31:51014 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka.network.InvalidRequestException: Error getting request for apiKey: 3 and apiVersion: 2
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.liftedTree2$1(RequestChannel.scala:95)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:87)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:488)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:483)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at kafka.network.Processor.processCompletedReceives(SocketServer.scala:483)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:413)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version for API key 3: 2
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.schemaFor(ProtoUtils.java:31)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.requestSchema(ProtoUtils.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.parseRequest(ProtoUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.MetadataRequest.parse(MetadataRequest.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:48)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.liftedTree2$1(RequestChannel.scala:92)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Do you really see `<hostname>` ? Or have you obfuscated the actual host name? If the former, your property has a bad value; if the latter, it's probably a network issue.

Comment: Yes , I see the actual hostname. I removed it while creating this post.

Comment: Check the server logs and look at a network trace.

Comment: Try the console consumer with the real broker.

Comment: Sorry Gary, what is meant by real broker? I've added the error that I see in server log as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version for API key 3: 2`

Your client version is not compatible with the broker version.

See [the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/) at the bottom for the compatibility matrix.

Comment: Thanks Gary , I'll check now

Comment: I am using this version of kafka - kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0. I see that in the page list of compatible clients and spring-kafka libraries were provided.  I used the below , I no longer see the error but messages don't seem to be consumed from the topic. Should I use different version of client for the kafka version that I provided?                                                                                    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.10.2.0'
compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'

Comment: I don't know if the 10.2 client is compatible with the 10.0 broker. Sounds like it's not. Check the Kafka documentation.

Comment: Hi Gary , apologies for updating multiple errors in the same thread. If needed I can create a new question. I enabled debug and I see this error "Group coordinator lookup for group amcs-tas failed: The group coordinator is not available."

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for that.